# Ruby on Rails: meaning of Mysql::error

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, database

There was a SQL injection attempt on one of our systems (open source publication database called Bibapp https://github.com/BibApp/BibApp). It resulted in this error report:

```
A ActionView::Template::Error occurred in publications#index:

  Mysql::Error: Column 'authority_id' in where clause is ambiguous: SELECT `publications`.`id` AS t0_r0, `publications`.`sherpa_id` AS t0_r1, `publications`.`publisher_id` AS t0_r2, `publications`.`source_id` AS t0_r3, `publications`.`authority_id` AS t0_r4, `publications`.`name` AS t0_r5, `publications`.`url` AS t0_r6, `publications`.`code` AS t0_r7, `publications`.`issn_isbn` AS t0_r8, `publications`.`created_at` AS t0_r9, `publications`.`updated_at` AS t0_r10, `publications`.`place` AS t0_r11, `publications`.`machine_name` AS t0_r12, `publications`.`initial_publisher_id` AS t0_r13, `publishers`.`id` AS t1_r0, `publishers`.`sherpa_id` AS t1_r1, `publishers`.`publisher_source_id` AS t1_r2, `publishers`.`authority_id` AS t1_r3, `publishers`.`publisher_copy` AS t1_r4, `publishers`.`name` AS t1_r5, `publishers`.`url` AS t1_r6, `publishers`.`romeo_color` AS t1_r7, `publishers`.`copyright_notice` AS t1_r8, `publishers`.`created_at` AS t1_r9, `publishers`.`updated_at` AS t1_r10, !
 `publishers`.`machine_name` AS t1_r11, `works`.`id` AS t2_r0, `works`.`type` AS t2_r1, `works`.`title_primary` AS t2_r2, `works`.`title_secondary` AS t2_r3, `works`.`title_tertiary` AS t2_r4, `works`.`affiliation` AS t2_r5, `works`.`volume` AS t2_r6, `works`.`issue` AS t2_r7, `works`.`start_page` AS t2_r8, `works`.`end_page` AS t2_r9, `works`.`abstract` AS t2_r10, `works`.`notes` AS t2_r11, `works`.`links` AS t2_r12, `works`.`work_state_id` AS t2_r13, `works`.`work_archive_state_id` AS t2_r14, `works`.`publication_id` AS t2_r15, `works`.`publisher_id` AS t2_r16, `works`.`archived_at` AS t2_r17, `works`.`created_at` AS t2_r18, `works`.`updated_at` AS t2_r19, `works`.`original_data` AS t2_r20, `works`.`batch_index` AS t2_r21, `works`.`scoring_hash` AS t2_r22, `works`.`publication_date` AS t2_r23, `works`.`language` AS t2_r24, `works`.`copyright_holder` AS t2_r25, `works`.`peer_reviewed` AS t2_r26, `works`.`machine_name` AS t2_r27, `works`.`publication_place` AS t2_r28, `works!
 `.`sponsor` AS t2_r29, `works`.`date_range` AS t2_r30, `works`!
 .`identifier` AS t2_r31, `works`.`medium` AS t2_r32, `works`.`degree_level` AS t2_r33, `works`.`discipline` AS t2_r34, `works`.`instrumentation` AS t2_r35, `works`.`admin_definable` AS t2_r36, `works`.`user_definable` AS t2_r37, `works`.`authority_publication_id` AS t2_r38, `works`.`authority_publisher_id` AS t2_r39, `works`.`initial_publication_id` AS t2_r40, `works`.`initial_publisher_id` AS t2_r41, `works`.`location` AS t2_r42, `works`.`invited` AS t2_r43, `works`.`open_access` AS t2_r44 FROM `publications` LEFT OUTER JOIN `publishers` ON `publishers`.`id` = `publications`.`publisher_id` LEFT OUTER JOIN `works` ON `works`.`publication_id` = `publications`.`id` AND work_state_id = 3 WHERE (publications.id = authority_id) AND (upper(name) like '(SELECT 1795 FROM(SELECT COUNT(*),CONCAT(0x716b6b6a71,(SELECT (ELT(1795=1795,1))),0x7178767871,FLOOR(RAND(0)*2))x FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CHARACTER_SETS GROUP BY x)a)%') ORDER BY upper(name)
  activerecord (3.0.17) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql_adapter.rb:289:in `query'
```

I want to know what this 'Mysql::error' means here (EDIT: not the actually SQL error related to the ambiguous column, read the next line). Particularly I want to know if this query was ran on the database or not. I can tell that at least it failed but I can't exactly tell where. I would presume that Rails has ways of protecting against SQL injection before it sends a query to the database but has this failed? Bibapp is running pretty old versions of Ruby and Rails, 1.8.7 and 3.0.17.

For a bonus, how could I check if database was attacked if the database only logs long running queries?

Comment: Try to replace `authority_id` with `\`publishers\`.\`authority_id\``

Comment: `Column 'authority_id' in where clause is ambiguous`: means you have the same column in two or more tables which you're querying on. You need to specify the table from which you need to use column.

Comment: Have you informed the project?

Comment: Why do you think this query was caused by a SQL injection? Btw Rails usually protects you from SQL injection, but only if you build your queries correctly (using the right helper) and old versions of Rails might have old and known security vulnerabilities.

Comment: If you scroll  to the right and the very end of the query you can see the injected SQL. Also, the query params look like: `Parameters: {"action"=>"index", "page"=>"(SELECT 1795 FROM(SELECT COUNT(*),CONCAT(0x716b6b6a71,(SELECT (ELT(1795=1795,1))),0x7178767871,FLOOR(RAND(0)*2))x FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CHARACTER_SETS GROUP BY x)a)", "controller"=>"publications"}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*What does this `Mysql::Error` mean?*

You are querying data from multiple tables by joining `publications`, `publishers`and `works`. And it is not clear to MySQL from which table you want to receive `authority_id`, because at least two of the three tables have a column with that name. Therefore MySQL raised this error.

*Was that query ran against the database?*

Yes because the error was raised by MySQL not be Rails.

*Can I check I if the database was attacked if I only log slow queries?*

No. If you do not log all queries then you aren't able to tell which queries have been run against the database.

Comment: as a note, i was able to find the query in the mysql logs, proving that it was ran by mysql.